# Microsoft Access Form Query

Tags: ms-access

I have created a form which allows users to search for data within the database via a form.

The database is restricted and the users are only able to navigate via buttons and forms.

At present, I have developed a form and a query which takes the criteria from a field within the form and then runs the query.

This is the code I use within the query to take the data from the form field:

`[Forms]![Query].[refCriteria]`

This code is featured under the "Criteria" section of the query design under the `Ref` field.

However, the query won't work when there is more than one criteria.  I have tried entering the following code under the `CCG` field:

`[Forms]![Query].[ccgCriteria]`

I notice that when there are two or more instances of the above code within the same query, fails to produce any results.

Further to this, it prevents my users from querying multiple criteria which is certainly a feature that I require.

Is there a way to have any or all of the criteria potentially run via the same query?  The only way I can think of getting this to work would be to create numerous queries, all of which would accept a different search criteria, but this is not a practical method.

Answer (score 0):

Query will produce results if you enter both search criteria and you have rows with both fields equal search criteria. If you need to be able to search by just one criteria, leaving some of other search fields empty, use for each column criteria like this:

```
WHERE
[ref]=[Forms]![Query].[refCriteria] or Nz([Forms]![Query].[refCriteria],"")="" AND
[cgc]=[Forms]![Query].[ccgCriteria] or Nz([Forms]![Query].[ccgCriteria],"")=""
```

I'd recommend to type the criteria in SQL mode, in graphic mode Access will produce constructions much harder to understand, especially if you have more than 2 search fields.

Comment: I see.  So what if I choose to use a single text field to use as the query criteria and the user clicks the button where they want to search?  For example, they will enter `London` into the search field, and then can click the `Ref`, `CCG` or any other button to search in that particular field.  How can that be done?

Comment: There are few variants of implementation: 1) by button click you can copy search criteria to hidden fields for Ref, CGC etc search criteria and requery, 2) generate full SQL string depending on search criteria and button clicked, 3)  create query with parameters, then by button click supply one or more parameters to query, open recordset based on this query and replace form's recordset by created recordset. #1 is easiest, I prefer #2.

Comment: I agree, the second sounds like the better option.  Would you mind providing some example code around how to do this?

Comment: You can find examples in the Internet. For instance this one: http://www.iaccessworld.com/create-search-form-using-vba-ms-access/